# index:length(......) : argument of length 0

Tags: r

I am trying to use the following defined function to calculate variable.

I have figure out that is **Function(0:n)** and **Function(0:last(age_mortality))** led the error. **However, my purpose is that I can get a vector start from 0 to n**

Anyone know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There several errors and warnings that pop up once this is solved and I managed to bog them down.

- `age_mortality==age` => `age_mortality %in% age` : what you're trying to do is get the indices of the elements of `age_mortality` that are found in `age`, and this can be achieved by the second code, as the first will check if element 1 of `age_mortality` is equal to element 1 of `age`, which throws the warning as `age` is of different length than `age_mortality`. Apply the change by a find replace-all. This gets the function to at least output a result.
- `N = length(age_mortality[index:length(age_mortality)])` causes the following warning :

> In index:length(age_mortality) :  numerical expression has 81 elements: only the first used.

What you're trying to calculate is the the number of years remaining so I propose that you change it with : `N = length(age_mortality) - index +1`
also you'll need to change the line that follows with

```r
ax <- sapply(1:length(index), function(i) sum( (v^(1:(N[i]-1))) * L[(index[i]+1):(length(L))] / L[index[i]] ))
```

if this is not what you're trying to achieve comment and we will figure it out.

- Now we get 2 warnings that have the same solution:

> 1: In AnnuityDue(age + t) - nEx(t) * AnnuityDue(age + n) :
> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

> 2: In S * Benefit(0:last(age_mortality)) * (1 + f) + Premium * (e *  :
> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

And if we print the output of the `Benefit`, `AnnuityDue` and `nEx` functions we can see what's causing it, apparently some `NA`s, `NAN`s and `Inf`s are what's causing the different lengths of the vector. we can solve this by defining an `omit` function that takes as input a vector and only returns the element which are finite and defined, i.e:

```r
omit <- function(x) x[is.finite(x)]
```

then redirect the output of each of the previous functions into it before returning the value :

```r
Benefit <- function(t){
    ### your code here
    return(omit(B))
}
# same thing for the other functions stated above
```

And now the code works with no warning, not sure if the outputs are correct:

```r
> Insurance(age_x1=40, age_y1=NA, age_x2=NA, age_y2=NA, 
+           r=4, S=1, n=25, I=0, e=0, f=0, n_guaranteed=NA, 
+           PremiumPayment="single", PremiumFrequency="yearly", 
+           BenefitType_x="whole life assurance", BenefitType_y=NA, BenefitType_joint=NA, 
+           BenefitPayment="year end", BenefitFrequency="yearly", Policyholder="Group x")
$`PV Benefit`
[1] 0.2305597

$`PV Expenses`
[1] 0

$`PV Premium`
[1] 0.2305597

$Premium
[1] 0.2305597

$Reserve
 [1] 0.000000000 0.008509399 0.017309504 0.026403962 0.035796264 0.045489822 0.055485862 0.065786354 0.076391321 0.087299629 0.098510445 0.110019422 0.121823431 0.133915583 0.146289267
[16] 0.158935859 0.171845028 0.185004428 0.198400619 0.212018291 0.225840105 0.239847703 0.254020586 0.268336638 0.282771726 0.297301263 0.311898937 0.326537415 0.341188133 0.355821656
[31] 0.370408020 0.384917092 0.399318583 0.413582476 0.427679070 0.441579072 0.455254361 0.468678022 0.481824380 0.494669926 0.507192372 0.519371971 0.531190799 0.542633303 0.553686424
[46] 0.564339674 0.574584613 0.584415520 0.593828910 0.602823466 0.611400236 0.619562371 0.627314658 0.634663662 0.641617653 0.648186080 0.654379478 0.660209598 0.665688864 0.670830245
[61] 0.675647388 0.680153925 0.684363793 0.688290888 0.691949218 0.695352424 0.698514828 0.701448744 0.704168487 0.706688199 0.709024689 0.711218119 0.713232273 0.715455505 0.717778932
[76] 0.720412393 0.730978749
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. 1) Why the outcome for **Reserve** still just show one number not a vector?

Comment: @BocongZhao it's from the original code. to correct it you need to remove the newline from the `S*Benefit(0:last(age_mortality))*(1+f) + Premium*( e*(TermAnnuityDue(0:last(age_mortality))-1))` line

Comment: @BocongZhao I d be happy to help further as I'm currently studying actuarial sciences